# How to bind mouse action over multiple entry widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm able to bind a mouse action on a single entry widget, meaning, by default a value will be present in the entry box, if i click then the default will be removed. How would i do the same when loop is used over individual boxes. If i click on any entry box, the default value must be removed

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def hello(event):
    ent.delete(0, END)

for x in range(4):
   ent=Entry(root,fg="grey")
   ent.insert(0, "dd/mm/yy")
   ent.pack()

   ent.bind('<Button-1>',hello)

root.minsize(400, 400)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: So are you asking how to call the same callback on all entries when one of them is clicked upon? or are you asking how to bind the same command to multiple different entries

Comment: same command to different entries over the loop

Comment: Check out [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47928390/3714930) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55291506/3714930).

Comment: i edited the code where am seeing the change only in the last box irrespective of where i click

Comment: That's because at the end of the loop, `ent` is the last entry widget. You could replace `ent.delete(0, END)` with `event.widget.delete(0, END)`, but I'd recommend you take a look at the two answers I linked, they make a class inherited from Entry with this functionality added, which makes this a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're hardcoding `ent` in your callback. The `event` object tells you which widget received the event, so use that instead.

```
def hello(event):
    event.widget.delete(0, END)
```